# How to bind data to ComboBox from entity

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, entity

I have this code, but there is still no data in `ComboBox`.

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
      var xd = (from c in context.CHall
                orderby c.CinemaHallName
                select c).ToList();
      foreach (var c in xd)
      {
           cbCinemaHall.ItemsSource = c.CinemaHallName;
           cbCinemaHall.DisplayMemberPath = "CinemaHallName";
      }                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `foreach` for this purpose. Just set the `ItemsSource` of your `ComboBox` to `xd`. Like this:

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
     var xd = (from c in context.CHall
               orderby c.CinemaHallName
               select c).ToList();
     cbCinemaHall.ItemsSource = xd;
     cbCinemaHall.DisplayMemberPath = "CinemaHallName"; 
}
```